# How to add field/properties to a Trello Card. Specifically I want to set a CRM backlink in Trello cards

Tags: url, trello

## TL;DR

How can I add custom fields/properties to a trello card? Any built-in feature? Any ready-to-use free power-up? If now, can I implement this inside my own power-up?

If it's a free-text key/values, okey. But ideally I'd love to set the type of the field to URL.

And even better I'd love to have a small program that deals with the URL display.

Also i'd be idea to able to filter cards in trello by that new field of the card.

## Context

I use trello to organize my priorities and day-to-day.

But the source of truth for our company is a CRM.

I usually use a link inside trello, in the main text, to place a backlink, like this:

[image: FollowUp backlink in Trello]

I want to know if there's any way (free power-up or whatever) that allows me to add "fields / properties" to my cards in Trello and add a field keyed "FollowUp" that is of type "URL".

Still better would be a mini-program that takes the field as an ID and displays the full-URL so if ever one day the base-URL changes, all the cards are automatically displaying the new URL based on a new configuration and a field value.

Having that inside the text is okey. But having a specific field and being able to "filter out" cards in function of the fields like "search all cards with tag `abcdef` which do not have the backlink URL setup" would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this which would work with your own API requests to Trello would be to use custom fields. However, you need to be on a paid Trello plan for that to work. If you don't want to pay the $5 a month for that you can't use custom fields.

There is an overview of custom fields here https://www.bluecatreports.com/blog/trello-custom-fields-how-to-and-examples/ if you are unfamiliar with them :)